# Android - Local Unit testing for file exists

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit

What would be the recomended approach(if any) to test the following code under a Local Unit test class in a Android project?

```
public static boolean internalAppFolderExists() {
    File file = new File(getDefaultStoragePath() + "/env/app");
    return file.exists();
}
```

Would it be better to just refactor this kind of code in any way?